# Lua equivalent of Object.assign

Tags: lua, variable-assignment

I'm new to Lua (proficient in JavaScript) and I want to assign some values to an object inside another object, something like this:

```
grandparent.parent.member.prop1 = "val1";
grandparent.parent.member.prop2 = val2;
grandparent.parent.member.prop3 = {foo = "bar"};
```

But this results in a very long code, what can I do to make this shorter? Will something like this work?

```
ref = grandparent.parent.member;
ref.prop1 = "val1";
```

Even better, is there a one-liner like `Object.assign(grandparent.parent.member, {prop1 = "val1", prop2 = val2});` etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "something like this" will work exactly as you wrote it. There's no built-in function for your "even better", but you could write one:

```
function assign(tbl, props)
    for k,v in pairs(props) do
        tbl[k] = v
    end
end
```

Comment: Your solution looks good enough! Thanks :) I thought variables were passed by value so I thought my example would overwrite a copy of the original variable.. My bad not actually trying it. Thank you!